# Bluez 5 in Ubuntu isn't working

Tags: bluetooth

I've installed the Bluez 5 package from source.

When I run the interactive command from terminal: bluetoothctl, the interactive mode starts, and the prompt changes to Bluetooth.

When I click on show: I get the error message:

> No default controller available.

How can I get Bluez 5 to recognize my Bluetooth adapter?

Answer (score 0):

The command `hciconfig` (HCI device configuration utility) is the main command for controller-related configurability. Try one of these two commands:

```
hciconfig hci0 up
hciconfig hci0 reset
```

If nothing happens, see what `hcitool dev` returns.